# how to remove observations in R dependent on a specific condition

Tags: r

I am trying to drop observations in R from my dataset. I need each Person_ID to have wave 0 AND (wave 1 OR wave 3 OR wave 6 OR wave 12 OR wave 18). Can someone help me?

Initial dataset

```
Person_ID   wave
    1            0
    1            1
    1            3
    1            6
    1            12
    1            18
    2            0
    3            0
    3            1
    4            6
    4            12
```

Wanted result

```
Person_ID   wave
    1            0
    1            1
    1            3
    1            6
    1            12
    1            18
    3            0
    3            1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a grouped filter. We keep a person if both 0 and any of 1, 3, 6, 12, 18 are in their corresponding `wave` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- read_table2(
  "Person_ID   wave
    1            0
    1            1
    1            3
    1            6
    1            12
    1            18
    2            0
    3            0
    3            1
    4            6
    4            12"
)
tbl %>%
  group_by(Person_ID) %>%
  filter(0 %in% wave, any(c(1, 3, 6, 12, 18) %in% wave))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#> # Groups:   Person_ID [2]
#>   Person_ID  wave
#>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1     0
#> 2         1     1
#> 3         1     3
#> 4         1     6
#> 5         1    12
#> 6         1    18
#> 7         3     0
#> 8         3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this in `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, Person_ID %in% intersect(Person_ID[wave %in% c(1, 3, 6, 12, 18)],
           Person_ID[!wave])),]
#  Person_ID wave
#1         1    0
#2         1    1
#3         1    3
#4         1    6
#5         1   12
#6         1   18
#8         3    0
#9         3    1
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Person_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
  3L, 4L, 4L), wave = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
  12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```